# Why can't I switch my stylesheets?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am trying to get some html and an external js file to work in tandem to allow users to switch stylesheets with the click of a button at the bottom of my homepage and for some reason it will not work.

The js file:

```
function setActiveStyleSheet( title ) {
    var i, a, main;
    for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
            && a.getAttribute("title")) {
        a.disabled = true;
        if(a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

and the html:

```
<head>
    <script 
        type="text/javascript" src="./styleswitcher.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="style1.css" title="black">
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="style2.css" title="photo" />
</head>
<body>
.
.
.
<footer>
<form>
        <ul class="styleswitcher">
            <li><input type="submit"
                    onclick="setActiveStyleSheet(black);"
                    value="Style 1" id="stylebutton" />
            </li>
            <li><input type="submit"
                    onclick="setActiveStyleSheet(photo);"
                    value="Style 2" id="stylebutton" />
            </li>
        </ul>
</form>
```

I am also trying to set up saving the style in cookie, but have read that not all browsers accept cookies for local files (I don't have a domain space yet), so I'll wait to do that later.

Thanks

[EDIT] Sorry I actually do have the links in my head, don't know why I didn't copy them - fixed now ;). Still doesn't work.

Comment: What a strange construct you're using for `for` loop. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What does your error console say? I will bet you need some single quotes in here because you are passing in a string: onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('photo');"

Comment: aside from the above comment, it doesn't look like your doing anything but disabling the button?

Comment: This is to search through all declared stylesheets in <head> that begin with <link.... If it sees rel="style..." first, that is the active sheet; if it doesn't, that is the alternate sheet.

Comment: Avoid using the same value in several id attributes. These values are supposed to be unique, If you want to loop through your buttons, use the class attribute instead.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus added single quotes - still doesn't work.

Comment: @BobM I use the same id so that I can alter the style of both buttons in my css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

1) Your HTML misses the declaration of the default and alternative stylesheets.
Your JS code is looping through the link tags, but there are none in your code.

2) Unless black and photo are variables, you need to wrap them with quotes, like `setActiveStyleSheet('photo')`. Make sure the link's title attributes match to photo or black.

Source of your code: http://alistapart.com/article/alternate/. Read it, it's useful.

Comment: Is this still something that browsers support? The article is from 2001, and the web has moved away from giving the user control over site appearance since then.

Comment: Sorry, didn't copy the links in like I should have - fixed but still not working.

Comment: @Cormorant I didn't notice your buttons were "submit" ones. Try using `<input type="button">` instead. Submit buttons may make you leave the page (to the same page as there's no action attribute) and prevent the JavaScript from running.

Comment: @ehdv : this is HTML 4 and HTML 5 is still not a complete/recommended specification yet (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5#Plan_2014). So I believe this is still relevant.

Comment: @Cormorant okay, I think I found the issue. The for loop is wrong. See duplicate answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345985/javascript-stylesheet-switcher-not-working?rq=1

Comment: @BobM Thanks! All of your suggestions helped!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to complete add or remove the link elements from the DOM... Not just disable them:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Comment: Some browsers (Mozilla Suite) list all available alternate stylesheets. Also, they might cache them in order to accelerate page re-rendering. Removing the link elements would prevent all of this. Finally you want to make sure to remove only "alternate stylesheet" link elements, as the link element can be used for other purposes (printing, other devices, etc.)